# How to solve !action_type.empty(): Unknown action hi in contract hello?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, action, c++, error

I am following this doc: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract.

This is the `hello.cpp` contract code which is successfully deployed:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
using namespace eosio;

class hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]]
      void testit() {
         print( "Hello, ");
      }
};
EOSIO_DISPATCH( hello, (testit))
```

When I call `cleos push action hello testit '[]' -p  hello@active`, this error is shown on the console:

> !action_type.empty(): Unknown action testit in contract
>   hello

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as shown in this issue https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/214, the generation of the abi is not correct, and sometimes - always in my case - the `.abi` file is empty.

The solution that you can use now is literally writing your own `.abi` file. Luckly, I had an old version of the same contract compiled with the old `eosiocpp`, and the `.abi` was exactly what I needed. So, I just used that, and everything worked.

Comment: What version of eosio.cdt do you use? The latest version (1.6.1) uses different ABI generation process, so many empty ABI cases are resolved. If you use previous version, I recommend upgrading it.